# How do I fix Connect Document error in Tinylicious server?

Tags: fluid-framework

Sometimes when I restart my Tinylicious server, I receive the following error many times in the server logs.

`Connect Document error: {} {"messageMetaData":{"documentId":"1608426861167","tenantId":"tinylicious"},"label":"winston","timestamp":"2020-12-20T21:20:50.591Z"}`

What exactly does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is created when we fail to make a socketio connection. You can see our code to create the connection [here](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/8ac5feaa718336b1322ad36857bb2522e3f5b281/server/routerlicious/packages/lambdas/src/alfred/index.ts#L148) and the error message you're seeing [here](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/8ac5feaa718336b1322ad36857bb2522e3f5b281/server/routerlicious/packages/lambdas/src/alfred/index.ts#L321).

I don't believe this error will cause you significant issues, but it shouldn't be there. There's [an issue on the project's github](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/issues/4673) that you can add to if you're looking for more information.